# Saving a Formsets with request.user

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I save a formset with the request.user? I cannot seem to get my form to save the request.user object on save when using Django Formsets.

forms.py

```
class CreditOptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    crew_position = forms.ModelChoiceField(CrewPosition.objects.all(), 
        widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('CrewPositionAutocomplete'), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CreditOptions
        exclude = ('user',)

OptionFormset = formset_factory(CreditOptionsForm, extra=3)
```

models.py

```
class CrewPosition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class CreditOptions(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, help_text='e.g. 1995', null=True, blank=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    crew_position = models.ForeignKey(CrewPosition, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from .forms import CreditForm, SkillsForm, OptionFormset

@login_required(login_url='/')
def add_skills(request, template_name):
    user = request.user
    formset = OptionFormset(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OptionFormset(request.POST, user=user)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.forms:
                form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully created your profile.")
            return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('skills'))
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset
    })
```

When I save, the user never gets saved. I have tried in my for loop:

```
form.save(commit=False)
form.user = user
form.save()
```

But this does not save the user as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing user as parameter has no effect since you've excluded it explicitly.
Just add the user while saving, like so:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def add_skills(request, template_name):
    user = request.user
    formset = OptionFormset()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OptionFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.forms:
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                f.user = user
                f.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully created your profile.")
            return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('skills'))
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset
    })
```

Also `form.save(commit=False)` returns a model object. So you should assign `user` to this returned object's `user` field.